# visual studio code show less languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fSlA.png)I'm writing codes with 2 3 languages of programming.
when I open a new file I need to choose the language every time.
now, there is a drop list with all the supported languages.
there is a way to make the list shorter when the user choose what languages to show because this is his main usage?

edit:
what I mean is fewer options on the menu because I constantly work with 3 languages now and then.

Comment: Why do you need to choose a language? Do the files not have a file extension?

Answer (score 2):

The languages that appears on the list are those *built-in* on VS Code, plus those that you *installed*. If you want to limit them, you must *uninstall/disable* the languages that you don't want to see.

To *disable* Built-in languages, hit `F1` and type `Show Built-in Extensions`. Then, expand the `Languages` panel and disable the languages that you don't want to see.

You could also *associate* your languages with already installed languages (related to the file extension), so you don't need to select the same language every time you open a file. Just follow this instructions [enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language)